# jquery mobile multipage dropdown not displaying selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, multipage

I have written my first jquery mobile site using their multipage template.

In my application, Changes in the main page can affect the selected value in a drop down in a sub page. The first time I go to the sub page, the correct option is selected and displayed. After that, when I go to the sub page, the correct option is *selected* (ticked), but the wrong option is displayed.

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate this... http://jsfiddle.net/afePj/2/

page one lets you select an option...

```
<select name="selectname1" id="selectid1" onChange="changePageTwo()">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

...and sets the selected value on page two to match...

```
function changePageTwo() {
    select1 = document.getElementById('selectid1');
    select2 = document.getElementById('selectid2');
    select2.selectedIndex = select1.selectedIndex;
}
```

...when you arrive on page two I would like the selected value to be displayed. But after the page has been displayed once, the option it shows never changes...

```
<select name="selectname2" id="selectid2">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas about how I can make the sub page display the selected value?

Thanks

Comment: You need to refresh the selectmenu widget `$('selectid2').selectmenu('refrresh')`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Jack - worked in jsfiddle and on my real site :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update a select menu in jQuery Mobile you need to call the [select menu widget's](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/) [refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) menu so that the display is updated to match the native elements

For example

```
$('selectid2').selectmenu('refresh');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afePj/4/

Comment: Your welcome, Glad to help. You might want to scan through the JQM [faq](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/) for some of the comman *gotachas* that you might encounter while starting out with JQM.